# How to know if today's date is in a date range?

Tags: ruby, date, range

I have an event with `start_time` and `end_time` and want to check if the event is "in progress". That would be to check if today's date is in the range between the two dates.

How would you do this in a function?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### Use `===`

---

Actually, there is an operator that will do this. Make a `Range` and compare `Time` objects to it using the `===` operator.

```
start   = Time.now.to_i

range   = start..(start + 2)
inside  = start + 1
outside = start + 3        # ok, now...

range === inside  # true
range === outside # false
```

---

<sup>*Update post-comment-flood:* This version works well everywhere. (In Rails, in Ruby 1, and in Ruby 2.) The earlier `irb` example also worked fine but the interactive example wasn't always reproduced correctly in some experiments. This one is easier to cut-and-paste.</sup>

It's all straightened out now.

Comment: Does not work in Rails 3 on Ruby 1.8.7, So I prefer @heathd answer.

Comment: Getting TypeError: Can't iterate from time in ruby 2.0

Comment: What is the catch here? Like the other two comments, I tried this code exactly, and get the same error. Why did 19 people up vote this answer? Did it ever work? heathd's answer does work for me.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. Perhaps it worked in an older version, but doesn't appear to anymore.

Comment: Ok, fixed for Ruby 2, will comment on why later.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.2.2, I'm guessing because I'm not using Rails. [heathd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7176956/27358) (use `cover?`) works.

Comment: That was meant as an interactive demo. I've updated it with code that will work without typing delays.

Comment: Note: for this to work, you need to convert the dates `.to_i` and then used `===` to see if they are in the range. IMO, `.coverage?` is a better solution for dates.

Comment: can you do it with minutes?

Comment: We should also mention that range === time is not the same as time === range. range === time is equivalent to calling the #=== method on range. e.g. range.===(time) 

(https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Answer (score 259):

In Ruby 1.9.2  `===` doesn't work, I get an error:

```
irb(main):019:0> (Time.now .. (Time.now+1)) === Time.now
TypeError: can't iterate from Time
    from (irb):19:in `each'
    from (irb):19:in `include?'
    from (irb):19:in `include?'
    from (irb):19:in `==='
    from (irb):19
    from /opt/ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Instead use [`#cover?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

```
irb(main):002:0> (Time.now..Time.now+4).cover?(Time.now)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> (Time.now..Time.now+4).cover?(Time.now+10)
=> false
```

Comment: This works with `Date` as well `(Date.yesterday..Date.tomorrow).cover?(Date.today) => true`

Comment: `===` works fine in Ruby 1.9.2. You just forgot the `.to_i`

Comment: Bleh I was expecting `my_date.in?(my_range)` to work but apparently this is doing something else and cover? works fine in Ruby 2.3/Rails 5

Answer (score 40):

If you're using Rails you can use `TimeWithZone#between?`. You'd then have something like this:

```
> start_time = Time.zone.parse('12pm')      => Thu, 26 Jul 2012 12:00:00 EDT -04:00
> end_time = start_time + 1.hour            => Thu, 26 Jul 2012 13:00:00 EDT -04:00
> inside = Time.zone.parse('12:30pm')       => Thu, 26 Jul 2012 12:30:00 EDT -04:00
> outside = Time.zone.parse('1:30pm')       => Thu, 26 Jul 2012 13:30:00 EDT -04:00
> inside.between?(start_time, end_time)     => true
> outside.between?(start_time, end_time)    => false
```

Answer (score 21):

Because the date class includes the Comparable module, every date object has a `between?` method.

```
require 'date'

today           = Date.today
tomorrow        = today + 1
one_month_later = today >> 1

tomorrow.between?(today, one_month_later) # => true
```

Comment: Class Time as well.

Comment: This is way more readable than the accepted answer.
+1 for using the powers of Ruby correctly :)

Comment: Worth to mention that this is inclusive as well.
`today.between?(today, tomorrow) # => true`
`tomorrow.between?(today, tomorrow) # => true`

Answer (score 7):

summary

```
  d1      = DateTime.parse('2018/04/01')
  d2      = DateTime.parse('2018/04/29')
  outside = DateTime.parse('2018/04/30')
  inside  = DateTime.parse('2018/04/15')

  # include?
  (d1...d2).include?(d1)      # true
  (d1...d2).include?(d2)      # false
  (d1...d2).include?(outside) # false
  (d1...d2).include?(inside)  # true

  (d1..d2).include?(d1)      # true
  (d1..d2).include?(d2)      # true
  (d1..d2).include?(outside) # false
  (d1..d2).include?(inside)  # true

  # ===
  (d1...d2) === d1      # true
  (d1...d2) === d2      # false
  (d1...d2) === outside # false
  (d1...d2) === inside  # true

  (d1..d2) === d1      # true
  (d1..d2) === d2      # true
  (d1..d2) === outside # false
  (d1..d2) === inside  # true

  # cover?
  (d1...d2).cover?(d1)      # true
  (d1...d2).cover?(d2)      # false
  (d1...d2).cover?(outside) # false
  (d1...d2).cover?(inside)  # true

  (d1..d2).cover?(d1)      # true
  (d1..d2).cover?(d2)      # true
  (d1..d2).cover?(outside) # false
  (d1..d2).cover?(inside)  # true

  # between?
  d1.between?(d1, d2)       # true
  d2.between?(d1, d2)       # true
  outside.between?(d1, d2)  # false
  inside.between?(d1, d2)   # true
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rails, you could try this:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :015 > a = DateTime.now
 => Fri, 02 Dec 2011 11:04:24 -0800 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :016 > (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).include_with_range? a
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :017 > (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).include_with_range? a+10.days
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :018 > (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).include_with_range? a+25.hours
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :019 > (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).include_with_range? a+2.hours
 => true
```

Note: I just used `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` to provide an easy range. The important part is the `include_with_range?` method on a Range.

Comment: It looks like the Range#include_with_range? method provided by ActiveSupport simply adds the ability check if one range includes another range using #include?, for example: (1..5).include?(1..5). Other than that, it behaves identically to Ruby's native include? method. Since your argument is not another range, this ActiveSupport extension should make no difference. In any case, you should simply call include? and not include_with_range? since include_with_range? is simply an alias to include? (using alias_method_chain).

Comment: a = DateTime.now; (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).include_with_range?(a) returns false for me (not true) when I tried it in the console in Rails 3.2.8 and ruby-1.9.3-p194. (a.beginning_of_day..a.end_of_day).cover?(a) returns true, however, so I'll just use that instead.

Comment: a valid point. not sure why I opted to use `include_with_range` since it wasn't a case where a range was being compared to a range. Probably some kind of brain tumor. Good catch, thanks @TylerRick. @heathd answer is really the best one.

Answer (score 4):

If they're timestamps:

```
def in_progress?
  (start_time..end_time).include?(Time.now)
end
```

Comment: For me on 1.9.2, this gave an error `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`

Answer (score 4):

Checked is current date in between two dates. Using Ruby

```
currentDate = DateTime.now
start_date = "2017-03-31"
end_date = "2018-03-31"
currentDate.between?(start_date, end_date)

**Out Put Will be** true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

Thit may help some one out there.

ruby only can understand date between calculations if the date format like this :

```
.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

not

```
.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

If you do it the wrong way it will give you a false positive.

This works perfectly now

```
   if tmpadd182.between?(datebeginingmonth, dateendofmonth)
```