# Rails 3.1 Test Whether a Time Object is inside a String Time Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

The params string that indicates a time range

```
sched = "8:00AM-5:30PM"
```

There are start and end times stored in my database

```
client1.sched_start    # => 2000-01-01 07:30:00 UTC
client1.sched_end      # => 2000-01-01 17:30:00 UTC
client2.sched_start    # => 2000-01-01 08:30:00 UTC
client2.sched_end      # => 2000-01-01 16:30:00 UTC
```

How do I test whether a client time range is in the scheduled hours range, returning true or false?

So far, I have this, but I get true always and deprecation warnings plus it's really slow.

```
time_open = Time.use_zone('UTC'){Time.zone.parse '2000-01-01 '+sched.split("-")[0]}
time_close = Time.use_zone('UTC'){Time.zone.parse '2000-01-01 '+sched.split("-")[1]}
range = time_open..time_close
range === client1.sched_start && range === client1.sched_end
range === client2.sched_start && range === client2.sched_end
```

Here's an excerpt the warning

```
warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1
```

Also, the times are different formats. For example,

```
time_open # Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 UTC 00:00
```

These were helpful in getting thus far:

- [Rails ActiveSupport Time Parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354657/rails-activesupport-time-parsing%5D)
- [How to know if today's date
  is in a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521921/how-to-know-if-todays-date-is-in-a-date-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify your problem and see if we can set you on the right path.  `time_open` evaluates to the following value:

```
>> time_open = Time.use_zone('UTC'){Time.zone.parse '2000-01-01 ' + "8:00AM"}
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Let's convert `client1.sched_start` (I refer to this as `scheduled_time`) to a Time object (this step might not be necessary if `client1.sched_start` is already a Time object, check with `client1.sched_start.class`).

```
>> scheduled_time = Time.parse('2000-01-01 07:30:00 UTC')
=> 2000-01-01 07:30:00 UTC
```

`time_open` and `scheduled_time` are not equal:

```
>> time_open == scheduled_time
=> false
```

If we compare `time_open` to the same time, it will be equal:

```
>> correct_start = Time.parse('2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC')
=> 2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC
>> time_open == correct_start
=> true
```

- Edit - how to check if a time is in a range *

I think it is much clearer to check if a time is within a range by using the `<` and `>` operators:

```
>> start_time = Time.new(2013, 7, 29, 10)
=> 2013-07-29 10:00:00 -0400
>> end_time = Time.new(2013, 7, 29, 16)
=> 2013-07-29 16:00:00 -0400
>> subject_time = Time.new(2013, 7, 29, 14)
=> 2013-07-29 14:00:00 -0400
>> subject_time > start_time && subject_time < end_time
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That explains why the times were showing as different time formats. When I did `time_open.class`, I got `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. So I changed my open/close times to `time_open = Time.parse("2000-01-01 08:00AM"+" UTC")` and now they are both `Time` classes. But when I follow-through and make a time range and then see if my Time objects are inside that range. I get an error. `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`

Comment: @JHo - I updated my answer to show how I think you should check if a time is within a range of times.  Please let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I like this solution. It works for arbitrary dates and easily converts strings. This reference was useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609267/how-to-find-if-range-is-contained-in-an-array-of-ranges