# How Do I Specify Date Range in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 3.2 app, I need to create an `if` condition that checks what date range today's date is in.  Something like this:

```
current_date = Date.today

# if current_date is between 2013-08-01..2013-08-15
#   return 1
# elsif current_date is between 2013-08-16..2013-08-30
#   return 2
# end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521921/how-to-know-if-todays-date-is-in-a-date-range

Comment: I saw that question, but how do I make that work with hard coded dates, as well as returning a value other than true/false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudo-code almost has it, You can just write the following using `#cover`:

```
def date_range(date)
  if (Date.new(2013, 8, 1) .. Date.new(2013, 8, 15)).cover?(date)
    1
  elsif (Date.new(2013, 8, 16) .. Date.new(2013, 8, 30)).cover?(date)
    2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Comparable#between?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
if current_date.between? Date.new(2013, 8, 1), Date.new(2013, 8, 15)
  1
elsif current_date.between? Date.new(2013, 8, 16), Date.new(2013, 8, 30)
  2
end
```

Or date ranges: (see [`Range#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D))

```
case current_date
when Date.new(2013, 8, 1)..Date.new(2013, 8, 15)
  1
when Date.new(2013, 8, 16)..Date.new(2013, 8, 30)
  2
end
```