# .where method doesn't understand Date objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm having trouble with the first loop. The second one successfully fills the @res[] array whereas the first one doesn't.

```
@res = {}
[:disc, :wpmot, :df, :ptsi, :eq].each do |t|
   tool = Tool.find_by(name: t)
   p (to - from)
   @res[t] = tool.certifieds.where(date: to - from)
end
.
.
.
@res = {}
[:disc, :wpmot, :df, :ptsi, :eq].each do |t|
   tool = Tool.find_by(name: t)
   p (Date.today - 1.months..Date.today)
   @res[t] = tool.certifieds.where(date: Date.today - 1.months..Date.today)
end
```

`to` and `from` are defined as such:

```
from = Date.new(start_year, start_month, start_day)
to = Date.new(end_year, end_month, end_day)
```

I then printed both values to see if they correspond but they didn't.
`p (Date.today - 1.months..Date.today)` gave me `'Mon, 11 Nov 2019..Wed, 11 Dec 2019'` whereas `p (to - from)` gave me  `'(1/1)'`(sort of ratio between both dates). So I do understand that the first loop isn't working because the `Date` objects aren't correct. What is it that I'm doing wrong ?

Cheers.

Comment: `1.month.ago..Date.today` or use `where(Tool.arel_table[:published_date].gte(1.month.ago))`.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but this seems like a lot of Ruby logic that should be database logic instead. You're doing 10 queries where you could do one. Something like `Certified.joins(:tools).where(date: from..to, certifieds: {name: %w[disc wpmot df ptsi eq]})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first loop you used `to - from` and it results in number of days between those two dates.

If I understood you correctly you want to find all the `certifieds` between dates so instead of substracting them supply a `Range` as a argument to `where`. You did it in the second loop with `Date.today - 1.months..Date.today`.

You can build range between two dates using `..` syntax. Your where clause should look like this: `.where(date: from..to)`

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my problem. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387395/10648704) post that provides an example.